# Why is the brush preventing dc.js barChart toolTips to appear?

Tags: d3.js, tooltip, bar-chart, dc.js

I don't see why that behaviour was implemented.
Any good reason ?

Comment: Can you post some examples of what you're doing and how it isn't what you want?

Comment: It's just a general behaviour, nohing specific. In my case I have a barChart of daily sales and I would want to show a tooltip with the amount when hovering on a bar. But when the brush is activated, it blocks the tooltips.

Comment: In order to have a brushing function, a transparent rectangle that captures all mouse events has to be drawn over top of the graph.  That's what is preventing any mouse events from triggering the tooltip  event handler on the main graph elements.   If you want both behaviours, consider using a [focus + context](bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) layout.  That example uses plain d3, but you could recreate it with dc.js.  Just have two different views of the same data, one with the brush and one with the tooltips or other interactivity.

Comment: Thanks @AmeliaBR. I have tried that but the charts don't react as expected. If you have time to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846926/dc-js-charts-not-linked), that would be really helpful.

Comment: Good answer @AmeliaBR.  Do you mind adding it as an answer so that DC.JS doesn't show this as an unanswered question?

Comment: @DJMartin Done.  Thanks for the nudge.  I complain about the same thing myself!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to have a brushing function, a transparent rectangle that captures all mouse events has to be drawn over top of the graph. That prevents any mouse events from triggering the tooltip event handler on the main graph elements, and is the reason the [dc.js API](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-1.6.0.md#brushonboolean) warns that leaving brushing behaviour "on" will disable all other interactive behaviour.

If you want both behaviours, consider using a [focus + context](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) layout. That example uses plain d3, but you could recreate it with dc.js. Just have two different views of the same data, one with the brush and one with the tooltips or other interactivity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events to block 'mouseover' event  for brush so that tooltips are enabled. Then on chart you can create a custom 'mousedown' event and pass it to brush to enable selection

```
d3.select('.chartContainer').on('mousedown', function(){
                    brush_elm = self.scrubberContent.select(".brush").node();
                    new_click_event = new Event('mousedown');
                    new_click_event.pageX = d3.event.pageX;
                    new_click_event.clientX = d3.event.clientX;
                    new_click_event.pageY = d3.event.pageY;
                    new_click_event.clientY = d3.event.clientY;
                    brush_elm.dispatchEvent(new_click_event);
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using d3 code.  I realized that moving the tooltip event after the brush event fixed the problem.  For me, it looked like this:

```
 svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "brush")
     .call(brush);

 svg.selectAll('circle')
     .data(humidity_data)
     .enter()
     .append('circle')
     .attr('class', 'humidity_point')
     .attr('cx', function(d) {
         return x(d['date'])
     })
     .attr('cy', function(d) {
         return y(d['Humidity'])
     })
     .attr('r', 4)
     .attr('fill', '#428bca')
     .on("mouseover", function(d) {
         div.transition()
             .duration(200)
             .style("opacity", .9);
         div.html(d.Custody + '<br>' + d.City + ', ' + d.Country + '<br>' + d.Humidity + '%')
             .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
             .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
         })
     .on("mouseout", function(d) {
         div.transition()
             .duration(1500)
             .style("opacity", 0);
     });
```

This code allowed brushing, but retained the ability to hover over a circle element and see metadata.

Comment: Problem with this is that circles appear above the brush which is not good for usability